# git undo merge to master, but keep the changes locally

Tags: git

I had a feature branch and a master branch. I did some work on the feature, merged into master, pushed the changes, and then deleted the feature branch, both remotely and locally. So far, so good.

After merging, I realized there was a problem with my feature changes. I'd like to undo the merge on master, but still keep the feature changes so I can work on them again. How can I do this?

What I had originally:

```
A---B---C---D   [master]
     \      
      E----F    [feature]
```

What I have now:

```
A---B---C---D---EF (squashed) [master]
```

What I want:

```
A---B---C---D      [master]
             \
              EF   [feature]
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: `git checkout -b feature; git checkout -; git reset HEAD~1 --hard`  - "undoing the merge" is just dropping the last commit from master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many command sequences that can do it.  Here is one short one.

1. Make sure everything is committed (`git status`), so that step 3 can't wreck anything.  This is always a useful base step. :-)
2. Run `git branch feature`.
3. Run `git reset --hard HEAD^` or `git reset --hard HEAD~` (either spelling is fine, use whatever you prefer to type in).

Explanation:

- Step 1 should be obvious.
- Step 2 creates the new name `feature`, identifying the same squashed `EF` commit that `master` identifies.  This gives you:

  ```
  A--B--C--D--EF   <-- master (HEAD), feature
  ```

  The `(HEAD)` annotation shows which branch name is the current branch name, and therefore which commit is the current *commit* as well (in this case `EF`).
- Step 3 moves the *current branch name* to point to the selected commit.  The current branch name is, as we see in the diagram, `master`.  The selected commit is one first-parent hop back from commit `EF`: `EF^` means "first parent of commit `EF`" and `EF~` means "starting from `EF`, step back one first parent".

  The result is:

  ```
  A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             EF   <-- feature
  ```

  which is what you wanted.

Note that `EF~2` would start at `EF` and count back twice, to `D` then to `C`, so that `master` (still `HEAD`) would point to commit `C` instead of commit `D`.  The `--hard` to `git reset` tells Git to replace the index content with that from the chosen commit, and to update your work-tree to match.

Comment: Just to confirm, this would change the history of master, so that it looks like the EF commit was never made on that branch?

Comment: Yes, a reset --hard will change the history and it will look like the commit was never made there.

Comment: History, in Git, is commits. The history of some branch name is the set of commits found by starting at the commit to which the branch name points, and working backwards. So your goal was to replace the `master` history of `A-B-C-D-EF` with a history reading `A-B-C-D` (which is how it read before the merge). Everything you do in Git is, in the end, about adding commits and/or adjusting which commits are found by which names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset --sort master branch to the commit before merge `D` this will make you master head on `D` commit and the `EF` commit will be local on your machine, make sure from this then force push the master to remove unneeded `EF` commit then create new `feature` branch and commit the local changes to it again

Steps:

- `git reset --soft YOUR_COMMIT_HASH`
- `git status` // to make sure that your files not gone
- `git stash` // to make your is head clean
- `git push -f origin master`
- `git checkout -b feature`
- `git stash pop` // to retrieve the removed commit changes

reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---soft

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished in 3 steps with:

**On `master` branch:**

```
$ git reset --hard <Hash of D>    # D is now the tip of master branch
$ git switch -c feature   # Creates a new feature branch based on D and move to it
```

**Now on the newly created `feature` branch:**

```
$ git cherry-pick <Hash of EF> # Restores the EF commit
```

This is all that is required.

When a branch is deleted, any lost commits can be found in the `reflog` for a given period of time (*30 days by default*), so the `EF` commit hash could be found there just in case:

```
$ git reflog
```

Note:
The `switch -c` command is available from git `2.23.0+` and does the same as `checkout -b`.